# Spaces and suffixes in bash complete()

Tags: bash, autocomplete, compgen

I have two difficulties with `compgen` shell builtin.
I try show it in simple bash `_filedir`-like (using `ls`) code:

```
_myfiledir(){
  path="$cur"
  prefix=`echo /$path | grep -o "[0-9a-Z\-+_/]*/"`
  sufix=`echo /$path | grep "/[0-9a-Z\-+_]*$" | grep -o "[0-9a-Z\-+_]*$"`
  res=`ls -p $prefix`
  COMPREPLY=($( compgen -o nospace -W "$res" -- $sufix ))
}
```

In this case when `cur=="usr/li"` then `prefix=="/usr/"` and `sufix=="li"`

I have two difficulties. With space and replacement. For example:

```
$ script usr/li[TAB]
```

I get:

```
$ script lib/  <- additional space here
```

I need:

```
$ script usr/lib/ <- no space here
```

This code is only for example.

Answer (score 0):

**-o nospace**

This option don't work in `compgen` context. Use `compopt` to change options. 
In your case `compopt -o nospace` usefull for whitespace issue, and `compopt -o filenames` for filenames. 
Be careful with file names, you need add `$prefix` to `$res` variable. Option `filenames` only cut part of full path when displayed to user for autocompletition.